# Can any one understand me in the most easy way ? What is trace method in tkinter python 3

Tags: tkinter, trace

**What** is trace method understand me in easiest way **ever?**

Comment: Can you provide more details please?

Comment: Please bro help me to understand. Can you just tell me exactly how works trace method in tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

The `trace` method on tkinter variables lets you request that tkinter calls a function whenever a variable is set, deleted, or read.

Here is an example that shows a label being updated when you select a radiobutton:

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(*args):
    label.configure(text=f"Your choice: '{chosen_color.get()}'")

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="", width=20, justify="left")
label.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

chosen_color = tk.StringVar()
for color in ("None", "Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue"):
    cb = tk.Radiobutton(root, var=chosen_color, text=color, value=color, anchor="w")
    cb.pack(side="top", anchor="w")

# arrange for `callback` to be called when `chose_color` is modified
# note: "w" represents the mode "written". 
chosen_color.trace("w", callback)

# give the variable an intial value, which will trigger
# the trace
chosen_color.set("None")
root.mainloop()
```